# What is wrong with this reasoning about angular velocity $\omega$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, centripetal-force, angular-velocity

**Satellite $X$ orbits a planet with orbital radius R. Satellite Y orbits the same planet with orbital
radius 2R. Satellites X and Y have the same mass.**

What is $\frac{\text{centripetal acceleration of X}}{\text{centripetal acceleration of Y}}?$

My reasoning is that both satellites orbit the same planet, they have the same angular velocity $\omega$.

As such, $a_{c_x} = \frac{v_{x}^{2}}{r}$ where $v = \omega \cdot r$. Thus,

$$a_{c_x} = \frac{\omega^2 \cdot r^2}{r} \implies = \omega^2 \cdot r$$.

Doing the same thing for $a_{c_y} = \omega^2 \cdot 2r$.

Then,
$$a_{c_x}/ a_{c_y} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: "My reasoning is that both satellites orbit the same planet, they have the same angular velocity ω." 
That assumption is wrong.

Comment: @Azzinoth Thanks for the reply. I managed to work it out using the fact that gravitational force plays the role of centripetal force in this case. But I also thought that, if you take a wheel - outer parts are going to have greater speed than the inner ones, but their angular velocities are the same.

Comment: @nocomment Sure, this is true with a wheel where all points are fixed together and must complete a full round in the same time. But the two satellites are not stuck together.

Comment: Each circular orbit has its own velocity, which depends on its distance from the center of the planet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From X and Y orbiting the planet, it **does not follow** that they have the same angular velocity. The centripetal acceleration is what keeps the satellites orbiting. It is the acceleration, which corresponds to the gravitational force of the planet, which is constant for both satellites, as they are orbiting the same planet. As both satellites have the same mass $m$ we get: $$a_{c_x}=a_{c_y}=\frac{F_g}{m}=g,$$ where $g$ is the acceleration caused by the planets mass. So **what we can calculate** is the angular momentum that the satellites will have, because of this gravitational acceleration $g$: $$g=a_c=\omega^2r$$ $$\Leftrightarrow \,\,\,\,\,\,\omega_x=\sqrt{\frac{g}{R}} \,\,\,\,\,\,\wedge\,\,\,\,\,\, \omega_y=\sqrt{\frac{g}{2R}},$$ where $R$ is the radius of satellite X. Thus $$\frac{\omega_x}{\omega_y}=\sqrt{2},$$ is something you could calculate here.

Comment: Great, thanks for this. It makes sense now.